# Android dynamic radiobuttons id

Tags: android, user-interface, dynamic, radio-button

I am creating a number (count) of `RadioButton`s. I cant use `RadioGroup`, because i need 1 `RadioButton`, next to a `Button`, in each `TableRow`. Yet, as with all `RadioButton`s, only one should be picked at a time. I figured i could set the id, and read it on the `onCheckedChanged`, to change everything, but the one you clicked, to false.

```java
rb = new RadioButton[count];

For-loop....
     rb[i]  = new RadioButton(this);
     rb[i].setId(5000 + i);
     rb[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

And the `onCheckedChanged`:

```java
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
{       
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (buttonView.getId() == 5000 + i)
        {
            // Its the one
        }
        else
        {
            // Its not the one
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById((5000 + count));
            rb.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
}
```

I DO catch the right `RadioButton`s, but when i try the `.setChecked(false)` it gives me a `NullPointerException`, and i have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting ids for your `RadioButtons` from `5000` to `5000 + (count - 1)`(the `RadioButton` array has a size of `count` but the ids are until `count - 1` because you start the loop from `0`(?!?)). In the `else` clause you look for the `RadioButton` with the id `5000 + count` which doesn't exist in the layout so you end up with a null reference.

Edit :

The code to simulate a `RadioGroup` should be like this:

In the `for` loop were you build the `RadioButtons`:

```
rb[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkListener);
//...
```

where `checkListener` is a listener instance:

```
private OnCheckedChangeListener checkListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                if (buttonView.getId() == 5000 + i) {
                    Log.e("XXX", "Position " + i);
                } else {                                       
                    RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById((5000 + i));
                    rb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
                    rb.setChecked(false);
                    rb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkListener);
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: @user1285334 You look for a `RadioButton` with an `id` of 5000 + `count` and this steps over the boundaries of the set ids. Anyway see my edited answer for a snippet of code on how to implement the desired functionality.

Comment: Jeeesus, i see it now. OBVIUSLY i should ask if the radiobutton is 5000 + i, not 5000 + count. Stupid typo like that. Been looking at it for ages. Though - is there any reason you create the checklistener instead of just using (this)?

Comment: @user1285334 I didn't actually look at your code to see that you set `this` to the `RadioButtons` listener, also generally I don't make the activity implement those listener interfaces(`OnCheckedChangeListener`, `OnClickListener` etc).

Answer (score 0):

This is showing you NullPointerException because it is not getting id of checked RadioButton.Instead of this use isCheked() method to check weather radiobutton is checked or not.Try this one

```
  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
 {       
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
    if (buttonView.isChecked())
    {
        // perform your task here
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something here.........
    }
}
```

}

hope this helps :)

Comment: I dont really see the logic in this code. I think you have misunderstood my problem. Theese radiobuttons are NOT in a group. Which means, when i get the oncheckedchanged, and find that buttonview is set to true, every OTHER radiobutton, must be set to false. MY PROBLEM IS that when i try to set the other ones, i get the nullpointer.